# ViewPager creates duplicate views

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

This is the `PagingAdapter` I am using:

```
public class PagingAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
    Context context;

    public PagingAdapter(FragmentManager fm, Context con) {
        super(fm);
        context = con;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int index) {
        try {
            switch (index) {
                case 0:
                    return Fragment.instantiate(context, ActivityFragment.class.getName());
                case 1:
                    return Fragment.instantiate(context, GroupFragment.class.getName());
                case 2:
                    return Fragment.instantiate(context, MessageFragment.class.getName());
                case 3:
                    return Fragment.instantiate(context, NotificationFragment.class.getName());
            }

            return null;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            return  null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // get item count - equal to number of tabs
        return 4;
    }
}
```

This creates same view for first two tabs. I want separate content for all tabs.
I am placing `WebView` in all 4 tabs.

In Activity, I am doing this :

```
mViewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(3);
```

Comment: what do you expect ?

Comment: @Blackbelt : Thanks. I want separate content for all tabs.

Comment: each webview should load a different content ?

Comment: Suggestion : Switch to using `FragmentPagerAdapter`, as you only have 4 pages and you are anyhow saving recent 3 pages that are now off-screen.
Also, Can you show the webview loading code for the pages that show similar contents..

Answer (score 0):

First of all your method `instantiate` is returning a Fragment right?

Does it add the param implicitly in that method using `setArguements` if not you may want to change to it. On the other hand  FragmentManager will call default constructor of each fragment when needed. So you have to keep them (do not overload constructor) and in destroyItem try removing the fragment for real.

```
@Override
public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
    getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().remove((Fragment)(object)).commit();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `SparseArray<Fragment>` in your adapter, and in your `getItem` use `new` instantiate your fragments like

```
return new ActivityFragment();
```

If you want to add bundle info than first create your fragment than add bundle in your

```
fragment.setArgument(bundle);
```

And use these line in your deateyItem before calling super

```
if(0<=sparseArray.indexOfKey(position))
sparseArray.remove(position);
```

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by separate view? are you sure that you are not inflating the wrong layout in.

```
GroupClassFragment.java class
```

Do check int the method.

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View myCorrectView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_correct_view,container,false);
    return myCorrectView;
}
```